# Run java application using C# and get its output from CMD

Tags: c#, java, cmd

I want to run a Java console application using my C# program and get its output.

As of now, Im having a hard time running java.exe with arguments, in this case, the name of the .java file to be executed.

Assume the name of the compiled Java console application is: JavaConsoleApplication

It will print "hello world" when exucuted and I also put an JOptionPane MessageDialog just to be sure it runs when I executed my C# program.

My code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process JavaTest = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
JavaTest.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\xxxxx\java.exe";
JavaTest.StartInfo.Arguments = "JavaConsoleApplication";
JavaTest.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
JavaTest.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
JavaTest.Start();
richtTextbox1.Text = JavaTest.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
JavaTest.WaitForExit();
```

My problem right now is my code failed to run the Java application using the specified arguments above.

Any idea? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I found a SOLUTION but its quite odd. I need to put the JavaConsoleApplication.CLASS in my C# project solution folder. I guess the error in my code is the arguments? I can't figure out what alex want to explain : (

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to provide the class path (argument -cp).

First try to run your java application manually. You have to say something like this:

java -cp YOUR-CLASSPATH JavaConsoleApplication ARGUMENTS-IF-ANY

The class path is typically a list of jar files separated with ; (if you are on windows). Be sure that the paths to jar files you are providing are correct.

Good luck.

Comment: Do i Really need to include the CLASSPATHS since  my code only prints "hello word" ? I already removed the JoptionPane